# ACA NeoGeo Sengoku from the Microsoft Store is running too fast on my Windows 10 PC

Tags: pc, sengoku

I bought ACA NeoGeo Sengoku from the Microsoft Store on PC.  The game is running too fast. I have been trying things on my graphics card control panel but just made things worse. So I went back to default settings and thought I would ask around for some help.

I tried everything from this link and nothing worked: https://support.gog.com/hc/en-us/articles/213039445-Game-speed-issues-too-fast-too-slow-uneven-speed-

What can I do to make the game run like it was intended?

PC specs:
Intel Core i7 7700HQ
DDR4: 32 GBytes
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070
GDDR5: 8192 MBytes
Windows 10

Comment: What do you mean with "too fast"?

Comment: @Parrotmaster Probably the running speed of the game. A lot of older games were limited by the speed of the hardware (usually processor speed) and when you bring the game to newer hardware a single button press will send your character across the screen.

Comment: What is your monitor's refresh rate? I've searched and a user has posted [here that reducing the monitor's refresh rate to 60 Hz resolves the issue](https://www.trueachievements.com/forum/viewthread.aspx?tid=981577). Capping the framerate to 60 FPS with framerate-capping software such as [Nvidia Inspector](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/nvidia-inspector-download.html) or [Bandicam](https://www.bandicam.com/) might work similarly.

Comment: @Parrotmaster, imagine the difference between something like regular Street Fighter 2 and Street Fighter 2 Turbo.  The game is playable but it is not quite like how it was intended.

Answer (score 3):

I switched my monitor refresh rate to 60 Hz and that did the trick.  Found a link on how to do it here: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-monitor-refresh-rate-windows-10

Thanks @galacticninja!